# psql delete using join and return values

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have this query:

```
DELETE FROM c_table as c
    USING 
         a_table as a,
         b_table as b
    WHERE 
        a.id = c.id 
        AND b.a_id = c.id
    RETURNING a.*, b.*;
```

but I have a problem, I need all the rows of table B that have the a_id, using this query I'm just returning the first one

I don't know how I could do this, could anyone help me?

would I need to use two queries? first delete and then select with join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need all the rows of table `B` that have the `a_id`

Indicates a 1:n relationship between table `A` and `B`, and a 1:1 relationship between `C` and `A`.

There is no join condition between table `A` and `B` in the [`USING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html), which makes it an unconditional `CROSS JOIN` (Cartesian Product). The `WHERE` conditions connect rows via table `C`, not sure the planner will optimize that perfectly. I'd rather join `A` and `B` directly to exclude redundant rows early.

Even then, the query proposes the same row in `C` for deletion multiple times (once for every related row in `B`). Reduce that to distinct `c.id`. One way is to use `EXISTS` instead of a `JOIN`.

And yes, *first delete and then select with join*:

```
WITH del AS (
   DELETE FROM c_table AS c
   USING  a_table a
   WHERE  c.id = a.id
   AND    EXISTS (SELECT FROM b_table b WHERE b.a_id = c.id)
   RETURNING c_id
   )
SELECT b.*
FROM   del d 
JOIN   b_table b ON b.a_id = d.id;
```

Obviously, this only returns rows from `B` where the related row in `C` has been deleted.