# How to simulate delete cascade in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying delete a row, that has huge amount of relation, but when creating those relations, I don't use `onDelete: Cascade` option. I need a way to delete that without deleting all of it's relation one by one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "onDelete: Cascade"  If you want to give us the syntax of some ORM, you should at least identify it.  Or better yet, use SQL/DDL to tell us about SQL.

Comment: I'm now aware of a third option.  Either use 'on delete cascade', or deal with the consequences of not using it.

Answer (score 0):

See [psql delete using join and return values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307891/psql-delete-using-join-and-return-values).

I could resolve something similar: seats has a foreign key over aircrafts. To delete two aircrafts this solutions works fine:

```sql
with del_seats as (
    delete from seats 
    where aircraft_code in ('319','320')
    returning aircraft_code
)
delete from aircrafts as a
where exists (select 1 
    from del_seats s 
    where s.aircraft_code=a.aircraft_code );
```

Also, you can define a view and use a [trigger instead of delete](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createtrigger.html). But I think that the trigger on the view might be less performant.